# Multiple stores with different catalog and customers but same admin section

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, multistore

How to setup multiple store in magento with following configuration requirements :

- Different catalog.
- Different Customers.
- Different store themes and view if possible.
- Same admin-user access(common admin section).

Just the extensions and modules (Complete code files) from primary store should be common between these stores.

I am using Magento 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following url to setup multiple store in magento and also can be use same admin.

For different catalog:

- http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/
- https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html
- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-on-magento/

For different Customers - http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/customers/account-scope.html

For different store themes and view if possible:

**Method 1:**

1- system -> Design -> Add design

2- select my site and theme (modern)

and then go to `"index.php"` file u need to change the content like.

```
mask(0);
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '<your site code>';
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```